# How to integrate Email confirmation of user accounts in an ASP.NET Core MVC & Entity Framework webapp?

Tags: authentication, web, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1

I am new to web app development and recently used ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC and Entity Framework in Visual Studio 2019 to create a web app using the individual accounts authentication.

Currently, I have the website setup in which when a new user registers, the confirmation email could be done right away on the website by clicking one of the generated links by default.

What my goal is, to send this confirmation link to the user email for the confirmation process.

Any leads or the resources that I could follow to achieve this would be appreciated!

I have already tried few of the tutorials, some of them used the account controller to integrate this feature which I don't have in my project structure. I only have one default `HomeController` in my project.

Few tutorials add some classes in the services folder, which also I don't have in my project directory.

I have already scaffolded the `Register.cshtml` and `Login.cshtml` and they're now available in the `Areas/Identity` folder.

Many thanks!

Comment: Do you have any concern about this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The key to your integration is to set up an SMTP server for sending emails. You can try Gmail, but other email providers will do as well.

I will break down the problem into smaller tasks,

1. Set up a Gmail account for sending emails. Try to follow this [post](https://codewithmukesh.com/blog/send-emails-with-aspnet-core/).
2. Build a test page so you can test your Gmail setup.
3. Once you get the above working, you should be able to use the code for your actual user registration pages.

Comment: Heyy, Actually we are not allowed now to use set the security of gmail for the less secure apps. Do you any alternatives?